# How to wait on sequelize result before further action?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, sequelize.js

I am developing nodejs API. In some of my APIs, i need to check whether some of the parameters are unique or not in database and i need to code it in a separated method to share the function. (PS: I don't want to do it in sequelize models)

My api call like this

```
    var duplicate = checkUniqueEmail(req.body.email);
    console.log(duplicate);
    if(duplicate == true){ 
       //do something 
    } else { 
       //return error 
    };
```

The checking method like this

```
  function checkUniqueEmail(email){
    db.users.find( {
        where: {email: email} 
    }).then( (result) => {
        if(result !== null){
           return false;
        } else {
           return true;
        }
    }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

But finally i got `undefined` by console.log(duplicate)

The problem seems that i log the result before it executing and return some results,it should be a javascript async problem.

How can i modify my code to achieve my target?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `checkUniqueEmail` function doesn't return any value. You either have to rewrite it using `async` and `await`, or add `return` keyword before the call to the DB:

```
async foo() {
   var duplicate = await checkUniqueEmail(req.body.email);
   console.log(duplicate);
   if (duplicate == true){ 
      //do something 
   } else { 
      //return error 
   }
}

async checkUniqueEmail(email){
   try {
      var result = await db.users.find({where: {email: email}});
      if (result !== null){
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
}
```